# ggplot clustered barchart (sentiments by state)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following code for a clustered bar chart (using ggplot2) and for some reason the output does not look presentable, would anyone know what to change in my code? I am trying to cluster by sentiment (each sentiment has several states compared).

```
ggplot(data = sent_merge, mapping = aes(x = Sentiment, y = Percent, fill = State)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~Sentiment,scales="free_y")  +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  xlab("")
```

[image]

Comment: why do you need the facet?

Comment: add ``scales = 'free'`` to the facet arg. It's creating the same x axis for each facet even though you only need a subset.

Comment: ... and give `coord_flip()` a try to put the labels on the y-axis.